# awk output to a file

Tags: unix, file, awk

I need help in moving the contents printed by awk to a text file.
THis is a continuation of [previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460191/shell-script-to-process-files)
I have to move all the contents into the same file so it is appending.

To be specific

```
nawk -v file="$FILE" 'BEGIN{RS=";"}
  /select/{ gsub(/.*select/,"select");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0;}
  /update/{ gsub(/.*update/,"update");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0;}
  /insert/{ gsub(/.*insert/,"insert");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0;}
  ' "$FILE"
```

How to get the print results to a text file appended one after the other in the same file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I/O redirection are pretty basic when working with the shell. If you want to append lines, use `>>`. eg

```
nawk -v file="$FILE" 'BEGIN{RS=";"}
  /select/{ gsub(/.*select/,"select");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0;}
  /update/{ gsub(/.*update/,"update");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0;}
  /insert/{ gsub(/.*insert/,"insert");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0;}
  ' "$FILE"  >> newfile
```

please spend time reading up on shell scripting if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not much of an awk buff, but shouldn't the shell handle that for you?

```
awk YOUR_AWK_STUFF_HERE >> appended.file.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers suggest shell redirection.  Actually, `awk` allows redirection as part of the `print` statement.

```
nawk -v file="$FILE" 'BEGIN{RS=";"}
      /select/{ gsub(/.*select/,"select");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0 >> results.txt;}
      /update/{ gsub(/.*update/,"update");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0 >> results.txt;}
      /insert/{ gsub(/.*insert/,"insert");gsub(/\n+/,"");print file,$0 >> results.txt;}
      ' "$FILE"
```

From the [`awk` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/):

> The  print statement prints its
>   arguments on the standard output (or
>   on a file if >file or >>file is
>   present or on a pipe if |cmd is 
>   present), separated  by the current
>   output field separator, and terminated
>   by the output record separator.  file
>   and cmd may be literal names  or 
>   parenthesized  expressions;  identical
>   string values in different statements
>   denote the same open file.